# VBA code for emailing a selection from the worksheet to a provider

Tags: vba, excel, email

I wrote code that breaks up a report filled with providers into individual reports for each provider then saved them into a folder on my desktop to be emailed to the providers. 
Now I'd like to add some code that would automatically email these providers for me but would let me take a look first before being sent. Here's my old code.

```
    Sub VendorSeperate()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    wb1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name


    SaveFolder397 = Format(Now(), "mm.dd.yy hh mm ss AM/PM")
    SaveFolder400 = "C:\Users\johndoe\Desktop\Test\" & SaveFolder397

    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir SaveFolder400
    On Error GoTo 0



    [A2].Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

    batchdate = Format(Cells(2, 1), "mm.dd.yy") & " Sent " & Format(Now(), "mm.dd.yy")


    LR1 = Columns(1).Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For I = 2 To LR1 + 2


        If Cells(I, 1) = "" And Cells(I - 1, 1) <> "" Then

                providername = Trim(Cells(I - 1, 7))
                ActiveSheet.Copy
                Cells.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<>*" & providername & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
                Rows("2:" & LR1 + 100).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
                Cells.AutoFilter
                ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
                ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveFolder400 & "\JD2.0 " & providername & " Ck Batch Date " & batchdate & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
                ActiveWorkbook.Close
                Workbooks(wb1).Activate


        End If


    Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: what do you have till now for the sending part?

Comment: Please make an attempt at code for email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really Simple Code to send an Email with Outlook. Maybe this can Help you.

```
Sub mail()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = "abc@abc.ch"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Subject line"
    .Body = "Email text."
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
that's the part I was looking for since the provider's report is the active workbook before being saved and closed and returning to the original report.

Comment: @KnowMeNot: you're Welcome